# How to get image link from URL

Tags: php, html, image, domdocument, file-get-contents

How do I visit a webpage using `file_get_contents` and get the link of an image which is shown on it?

On the page https://www.roblox.com/thumbnail/asset?assetId=169454280&thumbnailFormatId=254, this line of code causes an image to be displayed:

```
<img class='' src='https://t0.rbxcdn.com/5d4449ed656bd92c4d51805ff8b72610' />
```

I am trying to use `file_get_contents` to go to this link and get the image link inside `src` but I keep getting this error:

> Object of class DOMNodeList could not be converted to string

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.roblox.com/thumbnail/asset?assetId=169454280&thumbnailFormatId=254');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getAttribute("src")`, i.e.:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = file_get_contents('https://www.roblox.com/thumbnail/asset?assetId=169454280&thumbnailFormatId=254');
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$imgs =  $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach($imgs as $img)
{
    print $img->getAttribute("src");
}
```

if you have several images on the page, you can use:

---

**Update** based on OP comments:

If **you're sure** you'll only have **one image** per page, you can remove the `foreach` loop and use:

```
print $imgs[0]->getAttribute("src");
```

Comment: I've looped the array to solve the problem, thanks for pointing that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There will only ever be one image on the page and I can confirm there always will be one

Comment: Cool, I removed my duplicate vote since your answer is complete

Comment: @TheCodesee I'll post an update code to get just one image.

Comment: @PedroLobito I am getting this error: `Fatal error
: Cannot use object of type DOMNodeList as array`

Comment: I've tested the code and it works as expected. You may want to copy the exact code above.

Answer (score 0):

I hate it when this happens, but some links are not actually the image *file*.  If the URL does not end in a file extension like **.png** or **.gif**.

(e.g. https://example.com/image.png ends in .png)

If you find the same images that ends in a file extension, that might fix it.